# Loading a table into PySpark Dataframe with limits

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, cassandra, pyspark

Is it possible in PySpark to load a certain number of data into the dataframe while reading it from the database? By certain number, I mean if a limit could be given to the `sqlContext` when reading it from the database so that the whole table doesn't have to be read through(as it is very expensive to iterate through 750K rows).

Here's the code that I'm currently using to filter out the required data. I have used Python3.7 and Cassandra DB apart from PySpark:

```
def connect_cassandra():
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
      .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
      .config("spark.driver.memory","15g") \
      .config("spark.executor.memory","15g") \
      .config("spark.driver.cores","4") \
      .config("spark.num.executors","6") \
      .config("spark.executor.cores","4") \
      .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
      .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE') \
      .master('local[*]') \
      .getOrCreate()

    sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
    return sqlContext

def total_bandwidth(start_date, end_date):
    sqlContext = connect_cassandra()

    try:
        df = sqlContext \
          .read \
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
          .options(table="user_info", keyspace="acrs") \
          .load()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    rows = df.where(df["created"] > str(start_date)) \
            .where(df["created"] < str(end_date)) \
            .groupBy(['src_ip', 'dst_ip']) \
            .agg(_sum('data').alias('total')) \
            .collect()

    data_dict = []
    for row in rows:
        src_ip = row['src_ip']
        dst_ip = row['dst_ip']
        data = row['total']
        data = {'src_ip' : src_ip, 'dst_ip' : dst_ip, 'data' : data}
        data_dict.append(data)

    print(data_dict)
```

As you guys can see, I'm trying to filter out the data using the `start_date` and `end_date`. But this takes too much time resulting in slow operations. I'd like to know if there are any DataFrameReader Options available while loading the table into the dataframe, so that the time taken reduces(exponentially preferred :p ).

I read the Data-Frame-Reader documentation and found `option(String key, String value)` but these options are un-documented so it's not possible to find out what options there are for Cassandra Database and how can they be used.

Comment: Have you looked at adding ".limit(100)", not sure if it loads and then limits or limits during load? Be interesting to know...

Comment: @hudsond7 it loads and then limits rather than limiting before loading, making the time consumed same. It was an interesting try, but to no avail

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. Interesting to know for the future though! Good luck with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you are using append method. Since you have big number of rows in your dataframe it's really inefficient. I'd rather use dedicated pyspark methods to achieve desired result.

I created some temp dataframe (I assume that you have created SparkSession) with 1 million rows on my local machine

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> n = 1000000
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
        pd.DataFrame({
            'src_ip': n * ['192.160.1.0'],
            'dst_ip': n * ['192.168.1.1'],
            'total': n * [1]
        })
    )
```

```py
>>> df.count()
1000000
```

Let's select only desired columns from your table.

```py
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df.select('src_ip', 'dst_ip', F.col('total').alias('data')).show(5)
+-----------+-----------+----+
|     src_ip|     dst_ip|data|
+-----------+-----------+----+
|192.160.1.0|192.168.1.1|   1|
|192.160.1.0|192.168.1.1|   1|
|192.160.1.0|192.168.1.1|   1|
|192.160.1.0|192.168.1.1|   1|
|192.160.1.0|192.168.1.1|   1|
+-----------+-----------+----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

At the end let's create desired list of data dictionaries. The easiest way to collect all the data is to use list comprehensions. Once we select columns that we want to combine into dictionary we can use `toDict()` method on each DataFrame row.

Nitpick:

- If you want collect all values use `collect()` method on DataFrame.
- If you don't know exact size of the DataFrame you can use `take(n)` method which will return `n` elements from your DataFrame.

```py
>>> dict_list = [i.asDict() for i in df.select('src_ip', 'dst_ip', F.col('total').alias('data')).take(5)]
>>> dict_list
[{'data': 1, 'dst_ip': '192.168.1.1', 'src_ip': '192.160.1.0'},
 {'data': 1, 'dst_ip': '192.168.1.1', 'src_ip': '192.160.1.0'},
 {'data': 1, 'dst_ip': '192.168.1.1', 'src_ip': '192.160.1.0'},
 {'data': 1, 'dst_ip': '192.168.1.1', 'src_ip': '192.160.1.0'},
 {'data': 1, 'dst_ip': '192.168.1.1', 'src_ip': '192.160.1.0'}]
```

Comment: See, I get the problem you tell about using `append()` in my code, but the actual time taken is when `created` is being checked in the DF, and further grouping and summation of data is being done. Which is why I wanted a solution which addresses filtering before the DF is being loaded. Though, I'll still apply your concepts since they're cleaner and more efficient. Help me if you could regarding the filtering part, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with filtering, but if so you should use proper bucketing  or partitioning on your Cassandra db. Sometimes you cannot speed up your code when spark have to make a lot of shuffles (which may be your case).

Comment: In that case, I might have to re-evaluate my cassandra db partitioning since my query is totally dependent on the `created timestamp` and have to figure out a way to speed this up otherwise this code will be nothing but a failed attempt.